# Water ripple effect on background of website

Tags: javascript, css, html, graphics

A client has asked me to apply [a similar water ripple effect](http://agilerepose.weebly.com/water-ripple.html) to the background image (and only the background image) on their website.

Considering that this is using a canvas, it doesn't seem possible. Is anyone aware of an effect like this that I can apply to just the background image on a page?

Comment: Is it impossible? No. Would it be quite some work? Yes.

Comment: Have you tried to put site content over canvas (with position: absolute) ?

Comment: Set width and height to 100% and put your site with position absolute and z-index

Comment: A similar thread that might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719668/an-html5-canvas-element-in-the-background-of-my-page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - Water ripple effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534598/javascript-water-ripple-effect)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For a high performance, WebGL powered solution, take a look at this project:

[jQuery WebGL Ripples](https://github.com/sirxemic/jquery.ripples/)

A demo is available [here](http://sirxemic.github.io/jquery.ripples/).

This technology is not available for everyone in every device yet, though.

Comment: Please guide me how to implement that? I need this damn good thing exactly. Please help.

Comment: @SFDC_Learner You can look at the [main link](https://github.com/sirxemic/jquery.ripples/) how to call the JS function to enable the effect in your page. You can also inspect the live [demo page](http://sirxemic.github.io/jquery.ripples/) source code to see how the HTML markup is and how the JS function is called.

Answer (score 11):

Have a look on these 2 demos, which i think you can get based to create yours.

[29a.ch](http://29a.ch/sandbox/2010/water/) and 
[mrdoob](http://www.mrdoob.com/lab/javascript/effects/water/00/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you are still looking but this has a good demo/tutorial on the effect:
http://code.almeros.com/water-ripple-canvas-and-javascript#.Ukpfe2QY2ok

Demo is here:
http://code.almeros.com/code-examples/water-effect-canvas/#.UkpiQmQY2ol

Answer (score 5):

Try using the script i have posted, it will work just copy and paste it into your code. i have explained with the comments in the code

```js
(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c'),

        /** @type {CanvasRenderingContext2D} */
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        width = 500,
        height = 200,

        half_width = width >> 1,
        half_height = height >> 1,
        size = width * (height + 2) * 2,

        delay = 30,
        oldind = width,
        newind = width * (height + 3),

        riprad = 3,
        ripplemap = [],
        last_map = [],
        ripple,
        texture,

        line_width = 20,
        step = line_width * 2, 
        count = height / line_width;

    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    /*
     * Water ripple demo can work with any bitmap image
     */
    with (ctx) {
        fillStyle = '#a2ddf8';
        fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        fillStyle = '#07b';
        save();
        rotate(-0.785);
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            fillRect(-width, i * step, width * 3, line_width);
        }

        restore();
    }

    texture = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    ripple = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        last_map[i] = ripplemap[i] = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Main loop
     */
    function run() {
        newframe();
        ctx.putImageData(ripple, 0, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Disturb water at specified point
     */
    function disturb(dx, dy) {
        dx <<= 0;
        dy <<= 0;

        for (var j = dy - riprad; j < dy + riprad; j++) {
            for (var k = dx - riprad; k < dx + riprad; k++) {
                ripplemap[oldind + (j * width) + k] += 128;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generates new ripples
     */
    function newframe() {
        var a, b, data, cur_pixel, new_pixel, old_data;

        var t = oldind; oldind = newind; newind = t;
        var i = 0;

        // create local copies of variables to decrease
        // scope lookup time in Firefox
        var _width = width,
            _height = height,
            _ripplemap = ripplemap,
            _last_map = last_map,
            _rd = ripple.data,
            _td = texture.data,
            _half_width = half_width,
            _half_height = half_height;

        for (var y = 0; y < _height; y++) {
            for (var x = 0; x < _width; x++) {
                var _newind = newind + i, _mapind = oldind + i;
                data = (
                    _ripplemap[_mapind - _width] + 
                    _ripplemap[_mapind + _width] + 
                    _ripplemap[_mapind - 1] + 
                    _ripplemap[_mapind + 1]) >> 1;

                data -= _ripplemap[_newind];
                data -= data >> 5;

                _ripplemap[_newind] = data;

                //where data=0 then still, where data>0 then wave
                data = 1024 - data;

                old_data = _last_map[i];
                _last_map[i] = data;

                if (old_data != data) {
                    //offsets
                    a = (((x - _half_width) * data / 1024) << 0) + _half_width;
                    b = (((y - _half_height) * data / 1024) << 0) + _half_height;

                    //bounds check
                    if (a >= _width) a = _width - 1;
                    if (a < 0) a = 0;
                    if (b >= _height) b = _height - 1;
                    if (b < 0) b = 0;

                    new_pixel = (a + (b * _width)) * 4;
                    cur_pixel = i * 4;

                    _rd[cur_pixel] = _td[new_pixel];
                    _rd[cur_pixel + 1] = _td[new_pixel + 1];
                    _rd[cur_pixel + 2] = _td[new_pixel + 2];
                }

                ++i;
            }
        }
    }

    canvas.onmousemove = function(/* Event */ evt) {
        disturb(evt.offsetX || evt.layerX, evt.offsetY || evt.layerY);
    };

    setInterval(run, delay);

    // generate random ripples
    var rnd = Math.random;
    setInterval(function() {
        disturb(rnd() * width, rnd() * height);
    }, 700);
})();
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.paperButton {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  z-index: 0;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: ripple 0.65s linear;
  -moz-animation: ripple 0.65s linear;
  -ms-animation: ripple 0.65s linear;
  -o-animation: ripple 0.65s linear;
  animation: ripple 0.65s linear;
}
 @-webkit-keyframes 
ripple {  100% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: scale(2.5);
}
}
@-moz-keyframes 
ripple {  100% {
opacity: 0;
-moz-transform: scale(2.5);
}
}
@-o-keyframes 
ripple {  100% {
opacity: 0;
-o-transform: scale(2.5);
}
}
@keyframes 
ripple {  100% {
opacity: 0;
transform: scale(2.5);
}
}


$(function(){
    var ink, i, j, k;
    $(".paperButton").mousedown(function(e){    
            if($(this).find(".ink").length === 0){
                $(this).prepend("<span class='ink'></span>");
            }

            ink = $(this).find(".ink");
            ink.removeClass("animate");

            if(!ink.height() && !ink.width()){
                i = Math.max($(this).outerWidth(), $(this).outerHeight());
                ink.css({height: i, width: i});
            }

            j = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left - ink.width()/2;
            k = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top - ink.height()/2;

            ink.css({top: k+'px', left: j+'px'}).addClass("animate");

});
});
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution as it does not rely on on OpenGL, any chance you can put this into a jsfiddle see we can see the example working live?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this ,if you upload your photo on https://imgur.com/ 
then after upload finishes press right click on image then copy image address and put it into your code just like this: 
background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/yourphotolink.jpg)
NOTE:after copying the link check that your link ends with .jpg or .png
if it ends with .jpg?1 delete ?1 so your link ends with .jpg

i don't know why jquery ripple effect doesn't support ordinary photos but these steps will solve your problem