# Ripple Effect for Image and not for Background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a Ripple Effect on the Background of the Image and Not for my Entire Webpage.

I saw the  Question [Water ripple effect on background of website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667487/water-ripple-effect-on-background-of-website) . But i need the ripple to be effected only in the background and not for the entire webpage. How can i do this. Here is the codepen i created.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dKCso

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/esteewhy/5Ht3b/6/.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just update another div inside your code ,

```
<div id="info">
<img src="http://tech.hu/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/chrome_logo.png" style="margin-   top:10px; "></div>
```

Here is another Codepen created by me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hhrnw
 check it out.

Comment: Just added the **bold**<div id="info">
<img src="http://tech.hu/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/chrome_logo.png" style="margin-   top:10px; "></div>**bold** inside the existing div.